# Why are keycode in keydown and keyup event different?

Tags: javascript, keyevent

I'm testing input on http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

[image: keycode in keydown and keyup event are different]

`keycode` in `keydown` and `keyup` event are different. Why does it happen? In addition are we able to find out what key is pressed from the given table?

I know we typically use `String.fromCharCode()`, but which value should I use, 229 or 49, or their average? LOL

I'm using Chrome Version 44.0.2403.155 m on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

See [Legacy `KeyboardEvent` supplemental interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#KeyboardEvent-supplemental-interface) (emphasis mine):

> Browser support for keyboards has traditionally relied on three ad-hoc
>   attributes, `keyCode`, `charCode`, and `which`.
>
> All three of these attributes return a numerical code that represents
>   some aspect of the key pressed: `keyCode` is an index of the key
>   itself. `charCode` is the ASCII value of the character keys. `which`
>   is the character value where available and otherwise the key index.
>   The values for these attributes, and the availability of the
>   attribute, **is inconsistent across** platforms, keyboard languages
>   and layouts, user agents, versions, and even **event types**.

That's why, according to [Legacy Key Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#legacy-key-attributes),

> Authors SHOULD use the [`KeyboardEvent.key`](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#widl-KeyboardEvent-key) attribute instead of the
>   `charCode` and `keyCode` attributes.